# Limit of an integral as a parameter approaches zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, limits

What happens to the following integral as the parameter $\varepsilon$ goes to zero (consider a>1)?
$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{e^{-\varepsilon e^{i\theta}}}{(\varepsilon e^{i\theta})^{a}}i\varepsilon e^{i\theta}d\theta$

Comment: Do you know Dominated Convergence Theorem ?

Comment: How does it apply to that integral?

Comment: First, try to find the limit when $\varepsilon$ tends to $0$ of the expression inside the integral.

Comment: I tried but I don't know what to do with that factor $\varepsilon^{1-a}$ (a>1) when epsilon goes to zero